# Change color of unchecked checkbox input CSS

Tags: css

How can I change input field's background color from default white to grey? I tried:

```css
input[type=checkbox]:checked::before {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input id="ch" type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

And:

```css
#ch {
  accent-color: #68e199;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input id="ch" type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

but it's still white: [image], I want this: [image]

Comment: Sorry to say this but checkbox theming isn't supported in most browsers yet.
a custom checkbox element is the only way for that. you can also use the `accent-color` css property to change the color of it's active state

Comment: HTML default radio and checkboxes are Operating System provided widgets you cannot modify unless the browser adds support for that (like `accent-color`). You will have to create a *CSS custom checkbox* for that, usually done by assigning `::before` and `::after` rules. Sucks for just a BG color, I know..